# How to add ansible loop with wait?

Tags: ansible

I am new in ansible where I want to start cassandra services in all my nodes with 2/3 minutes apart.
I have host file as:

```
[dc1]
dc1-node0 ansible_host=10.1.0.1
dc1-node1 ansible_host=10.1.0.2
dc1-node2 ansible_host=10.1.0.2
[dc2]
dc2-node ansible_host=10.2.0.1
dc2-node1 ansible_host=10.2.0.2
dc2-node2 ansible_host=10.2.0.2
```

At present, I am executing it manually:

```
ansible -a "service dse start" dc1-node0
```

... and so on with 2 mins apart.

I want to create a playbook for the same.

Please advice.

Comment: I see no reason for any loop here. Write separate plays. Ansible executes plays one after another. You can use `wait_for` task to ensure the service is running properly at the end of each. Or just a single play running against a group, but with `serial: 1`.

Comment: Btw "*I want to create a playbook for the same. Please advice.*" reads like "write this for me". I'm sure it was not your intention, so you might consider actually showing some attempt in your question.

Comment: You are right. My intention was not write something for me. I was actually looking to get some idea from experts as I am learning Ansible and writing playbooks. As I have nearby deadline to finish project, I was thinking to jump onto that part of my study which can help me to achieve that and I got it below.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

User `serial` and `pause`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - service:
        name: dse
        state: started
    - pause:
        minutes: 2
```